# Baby Rudin Theorem 9.17

Tags: real-analysis

In proof of Theorem 9.17 Rudin writes:
$$
|f(x+h)-f(x)-Ah|\leq \frac{1}{2}|Ah| \tag{23}
$$
It follows that
$$
|f(x+h)-f(x)|\geq \frac{1}{2}|Ah| \tag{24}
$$

I note that $f$ is a $C'$ mapping of a subset $E$ of $R^n$ into $R^m$ and $A = f'(A)$. I don't see how (24) follows from (23).

:

Comment: Intuitively this should make sense: Just for illustration, suppose Ah = 10. To be within 5 of 10 you must be at least as big as 5.

Answer (score 3):

Reversed triangle inequality:
$$
\left| |x|-|y| \right| \leq |x-y|
$$

Comment: Does not apply. See comments below or     http://mymathforum.com/real-analysis/51911-baby-rudin-theorem-9-17-a.html

Comment: Does apply. See below for why.

Answer (score 1):

if
$$
|r-2a| \le |a|
$$
then since $|x-y| \ge ||x|-|y||$
$$
|r|-|2a| \le |a| \Rightarrow |r| \le 3|a|
$$
and
$$
|2a|-|r| \le |a| \Rightarrow |r| \ge |a|
$$

Comment: Many thanks for responses. If |r-2a|>=||r|-|a||, how do you know |r|>|a| ?

Comment: whoops. typo. a should  be 2a.

Comment: "and" should be "or" depending on whether |r|>|2a| or |r|<|2a|. So this is not an answer.

Comment: "and" should be "or" depending on whether |r|<|2a| or |r|>|2a|.

Answer (score 0):

show |u+2v|<|v|-> |u|>|v|

Played with this in 2 dimensions and its true.

Assume |u|<|v|
Draw the vector 2v and from its tip draw a circle of radius |u|. Then u+2v is a vector from the base of 2v to a point on the circle whose length is always greater than |v|. Contradiction. Therefore |u|>|v|.

In n dimensions you would draw a ball of radius |u| at the tip of 2v and tnen calculate distances using the distance formula.

Note. |u+2v| is the same as |u-2v| because v can be + or -. It's just easier to think about.

Answer (score 0):

Prove: |u-v|<=1/2|v| -> |u|>=1/2|v|.

|u-v|>=||u|-|v||

Assume |u|<1/2|v|

|u|-|v|<-1/2|v| => |v|-|u|>1/2|v|

||u|-|v||=||v|-|u||=|v|-|u|

|u-v|>1/2v contradiction. so |u|>=1/2|v|